# How to book flights when travelling together with slightly different itineraries?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, planning

Two of my relatives are going to travel together from BOM-ORD.

One of them will stay in US while other will go back in a month or so.

How do I go about buying this itinerary?

- **Two one-way** flights and **one one-way return** flight (Expensive, as I don't get benefit of relatively lower costs of round trip)
- **One one-way** flight and **one round trip** (too much hassle, also not sure if it's possible to connect these kind of itinerary so they can get seats together n all, also what if I bought one ticket and before I get other one, thing gets sold out! :o )
- Better ideas please??

Thanks

Comment: My advised is google flight search engine like skyscanner, and check the price to see which is cheaper

Answer (score 4):

Book **two round-trip flights** and throw away the return portion for one of the passengers. People routinely do it all the time.

Comment: This.  Due to the craziness of airline pricing, a round-trip is often *cheaper* than a one-way.